# How to refresh directive that existed in template and directive has own scope for data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have - ng-view - template create item functionality and same template containing one directive that load the saved items.

Now, when i do save create item and immediately, its not refreshing list of items (from directive).

Can anyone tell me how I would resolve this, so, after saving item, immediately directive is refreshed.

Note: directive link function is making call to `$http` and retrieving data and populate in directive template. And directive element is added in other html template.

html template: (which has separate controller and scope).

```
    <div>.....code</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <parts-list></parts-list>
   </div>
```

directive code:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("application")
       .directive("partsList", function (partService) {
           return {
               templateUrl: 'partsListView.html',
               restrict: 'E',
               scope: {},
               link: function ($scope) {
                   $scope.partList = [{}];
                   RetrieveParts = function () {
                       $scope.partList=partService.RetrieveParts();
                   };
               }
           };
       });
})();
```

Comment: Can you add some code to understand what is wrong?

Comment: edited with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your ReceiveParts variable doesn't have proper closure. Also, are you calling this function? I'm not sure where this function gets executed.

```
link: function ($scope) {
               $scope.partList = [{}];
               RetrieveParts = function () {
                   $scope.partList=partService.RetrieveParts();
               };
           }
```

An easy trick I've learned that makes it trivial to execute some of the the directives linking function logic in sync with angularjs's digest cycle by simply wrapping the logic I need in sync with the $timeout service ($timeout is simply a setTimeout call followed by a $scope.$apply()). Doing this trick would make your code look like:

```
link: function ($scope) {
               $scope.partList = [{}];
               $scope.fetchedPartList = false;

               $timeout(function() {
                   $scope.partList = partService.RetrieveParts();
                   $scope.fetchedPartList = true;
               });
           }
```

Additionally, you'll notice the boolean value I set after the partList has been set. In your HTML you can ng-if (or ng-show/hide) on this variable to only show the list once it's been properly resolved.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried with $timeout but its not called. In main template where this directive is contained, it has updated flag value for its own scope.

Comment: Try removing the scope: {} from your directive recipe. It creates an isolate scope that might be causing you issues. It's hard to tell without all the code.

Comment: Ok, so in that, case, it will take from parent scope and applied to html. do I have to keep $timeout(..) ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code with detail. I would try it without `$timeout` first. If that doesn't work try it with `$timeout`.

Comment: It works without. Understood `$timeout` will call digest cycle too in case require to call manually. My case, it works without `$timeout`. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help :)

Comment: adding `$timeout` does not make sense here!

Answer (score 0):

Use `isolated scope` in directive:

```
return {
           templateUrl: 'partsListView.html',
           restrict: 'E',
           scope: {partList: '='},
```

and in `template`:

```
<parts-list partList="list"></parts-list>
```

Where list is where ui will update with updated data.

See how isolated scope using [basic Example](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/fzyo5p0t/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzyo5p0t)

Comment: How to pass list in directive? I have passed list object in directive with `=` but its not taken up in directive.